# How can I use hyphens in equation numbers, but periods in other numbers?

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath, amsart

I'm using the `amsart` document class. I want my equation numbers to count within sections independently from my theorem environments. But I want my equation numbers to use hyphens (eg `1-1`) whereas I want my other numberings to use periods (eg `Theorem 1.1`).

Ideally I want to set this up in the preamble, as opposed to having to edit the document class file.

Currently, my environments are set up to do everything except for the hyphens I want. I've pasted an abbreviated version below of how I set up my numbering (my document has more environments but that's not relevant). Can I get what I want by just changing that first line?

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\numberwithin{thm}{section}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
```

By the way, this is a convention used by AGT. I noticed this recently and like the idea because it allows the environments to not skip numbers even if there's equations between them, while at the same time avoiding them being confused with the numbered equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just write

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection-\arabic{equation}}
```

after `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection-\arabic{equation}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
\begin{equation}1+1=2\end{equation}
\begin{thm}Hello.\end{thm}
\end{document}
```